# Removing Left Recursion with Terminals

Tags: context-free-grammar, left-recursion

How do I remove left recursion on the following rule:

S -> aSAbb | aA

I understand how to perform it on S -> SA | A

which becomes S -> A | AS'; S' -> A | AS', but the terminals throw me off in this question.

EDIT:

Sorry, apparently I was confused as to what left recursion is.  I should have asked how to remove the left hand symbol from the right hand side.

Comment: It doesn't have left recursion, which is why you are having a hard time.  Left recursion requires the rule start with the same nonterminal it is trying to produce, e.g.,  S-> S ... ;

Comment: I don't think it's possible. The grammar seems to be `a^n aA (Abb)^n` and I don't think there is any way to bind those two `n`'s without recursion.

Answer (score 1):

The rule

```
S -> aSAbb | aA
```

is not left recursive. A left recursive rule has the form

```
A -> Au
```

where *u* is a sequence of terminals and nonterminals. To remove the symbol `S` from the right side of the `S` rules, consider:

```
S => aSAbb
  => a(aSAbb)Abb
  => a^n(aA)(Abb)^n
```

The role of the recursion on `S` is to produce this sequence. An equivalent grammar is:

```
S -> aKAbb | aA
K -> aSAbb | aA
```

The grammars are equivalent, since any derivation

```
S => aSAbb
  => a(aSAbb)Abb
  => a(a(aSAbb)Abb)Abb
```

is now just a derivation

```
S => aKAbb
  => a(aSAbb)Abb
  => a(a(aKAbb)Abb)Abb
```

and each derivation is terminated by `aA` (I think: please correct me if I'm wrong).